# Which Joomla extension is best for Billing and Registration accounts?

Tags: joomla

Hello all i want to know which plug in would fit best for having a person to hit a buy now for a monthly service and monthly billing cycle. but also make them register for an account and have them manage the account depending on which package they choose. this is for joomla thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

AEC is a Joomla extension designed specifically to manage subscriptions like this. [AEC subscription manager](http://valanx.org/index.php?option=com_zoo&view=item&layout=item&Itemid=118)

Answer (score 1):

If you are running your website on Joomla 1.5 then [PayPlans](http://www.jpayplans.com) might be the better choice. It blends very well with JomSocial and your design. And yes, its very much customizable.

Answer (score 0):

Virtuemart is a shopping cart system where a user can be made to register before purchase. The monthly billing would have to be done by your payment provider/gateway.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with [nBill](http://www.nbill.co.uk/) (a fully featured billing system for Joomla).